# Navigating from a FlatList Items exists in a Tab, to another Stack Screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, stack-navigator

**How The App works!**

I have an app that shows a list of names and after that shows the meaning of the Name depends on some preference the user choose it from a dropDowns.

So in total there is a Main of 3 Screens!

1. First: is the UI screen that asks user to choose data,
2. Second: is the screen that holds a list contains names, I list them using a FlatList (BTW the data retrives from a SqLite -not important-)
3. Third: is the Screen that shows the name's meaning,

I am navigating from the "Main-Screen" to the "NameList-Screen" then To the "NameMeaning-Screen",

The navigation to the "NameMeaning-Screen" done by pressing on an item from the List.

*Till here the app working nicely!*

I decided to add a new feature to the app and that to show all the names i have in my DB and show it in a screen that have two Tabs, The first tab shows male's names and the second tab shows the female's names.

I did that step too.

**But What am facing now is!**

I want to navigate from that tabs when pressing on an item from the flatList, and navigate to the "Third Screen" I mentioned above the name's meaning!

But it gave error that, there is no such screen called "NameMeaing" and then it says " Name screen Its not handled by any navigator", So as much as i understand, when am in the Tabs the program have no access to the stack Navigator and cuz of this it gives that error.

As much as i was able to find on Web, There is examples of navigating from tabs to another stack screens, but in the all the examples, the tabs were the main screen in the applicaiton, but in my case i reach the tabs after pressing a certain button and navigate to another stacked screen.

As a soluation for the problem i thought about creating a secondry stack navigator inside my Tabs.js file that contains the tabs but i couldnt, then i thought i should create a Tab navigator in my App.js adding it to my stack navigator that already exists there and compine them in a navigator container. Maybe this is the soluation but i couldnt complete the code and connect the dots. Any help please?!

This is a video of the app while working (The scenario)
https://youtu.be/dBLNF5zMCt0

This is the Error it shows:
[Error when i try to navigate from a tab screen to another different screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J3TF.jpg)

This is App.js file

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

import MainScreen from './MainScreen';
import NamesList from './NamesList';
import NameMeaning from './NameMeaning';
import NameListWithTabsAgirlAboy from './NameListWithTabsAgirlAboy';



const App = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainScreen: {
      screen: MainScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    NamesList: {
      screen: NamesList,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    NameListWithTabsAgirlAboy: {
      screen: NameListWithTabsAgirlAboy,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    NameMeaning: {
      screen: NameMeaning,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MainScreen',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

This is NameMeaninng.js file

```
 class NameMeaning extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }



  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    return(
      
      <SafeAreaView style= {styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>معنى اسم {JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('nameTitle', 'NO-ID'))}</Text>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
          {JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('explaination', 'NO-ID'))}

          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>

    );
  }
}
```

this is parts of Tabs.js file

```
This file have three classes in totall. BoysScreen, GirlsScreen and Tabs classes..

   class BoysScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {navigation} = this.props;
      }
    render() {
        let FlatListNames =  [];
        FlatListNames = boysNames();
        const {navigation} = this.props;

        function Item({ title }, {navigation}) {
            return (
                <View style = {StyleSheet.item}>
                    <Text styel = {styles.title}> {title} </Text>
                    <Text style ={StyleSheet.explain}>اضغط للشرح</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }


        function boysNames() {
            var boysNamesList = [];
            db.transaction(tx => {
                // boys names
              tx.executeSql('SELECT ID, Name, Explanation FROM Names WHERE NameSex=?', ["لـ طفلي"], (tx, results) => {
                  for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
                    boysNamesList.push(results.rows.item(i));
                  }
                });
          }); // DB transaction    
          return boysNamesList;
        };



        return(
                <View style= {styles.container}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={FlatListNames}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => 
                                            <TouchableOpacity
                                            onPress = {() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('NameMeaning',{
                                                nameTitle : item.Name,  
                                                nameId : item.ID,
                                                explaination : item.Explanation,
                                            });
                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                            <Item title = {item.Name}/>
                                            
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                    }
                    />
                </View>
            
        );
    }
}// ends of BoysScreen Class







    class Tabs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
    
    // I have tried to create a stack here but it gave errors and couldnt solve it
    //cont Stack = createStackNavigator();
        return(
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Tab.Navigator>
                    <Tab.Screen name ="FemaleNames" component = {GirlsScreen} /> //GirlsScreen is a class
                    <Tab.Screen name = "MaleNames" component = {BoysScreen} /> // BoysScreen is a class
                </Tab.Navigator>
        
               // I have tried to import NameMeanig class and navigate to it like this, but it gaves errors too.
               //<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={NameMeaning} /> 

            </NavigationContainer>
            
        );
    }
```

Thanks in advance, any help of how i can build this algorithm is appricated really..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with version compatibility, i was using React navigation V4 and V5 alltogether, After Searching more i have solved it in this way, Changing App.js and compine all the stacks and tabs navigators in App.js

Credit to this guy : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQVCkqvU1uE

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

import MainScreen from './App/components/Home/MainScreen';
import NamesList from './App/components/NameList/NamesList';
import NameMeaning from './App/components/NameMeaning/NameMeaning';

import GirlNamesScreen from './App/components/NameList/GirlsNamesTab';
import BoysNamesScreen from './App/components/NameList/BoysNamesTab';




const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
const MainStackScreen = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator>
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="MainScreen"
      component={MainScreen}
      options={{ title: "Main Screen title" }}
    />
      <MainStack.Screen
      name="NamesList"
      component={NamesList}
      options={{ title: "NamesList Screen title" }}
    />
      <MainStack.Screen
      name="NameMeaning"
      component={NameMeaning}
      options={{ title: "NameMeaning Screen title" }}
    /> 
      <MainStack.Screen
      name="TabsScreen"
      component={TabsScreen}
      options={{ title: "TabsScreen Screen title" }}
    /> 
  </MainStack.Navigator>
);

const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const GirlNamesStack = createStackNavigator();
const BoysNamesStack = createStackNavigator();

const GirlNamesStackScreen = () => (
  <GirlNamesStack.Navigator>
    <GirlNamesStack.Screen name="GirlsNames" component={GirlNamesScreen} />
  </GirlNamesStack.Navigator>
);

const BoysNamesStackScreen = () => (
  <BoysNamesStack.Navigator>
    <BoysNamesStack.Screen name="BoysNames" component={BoysNamesScreen} />
  </BoysNamesStack.Navigator>
);

const TabsScreen = () => (
  <Tabs.Navigator>
    <Tabs.Screen name="BoysNames" component={BoysNamesStackScreen} />
    <Tabs.Screen name="GirlsNames" component={GirlNamesStackScreen} />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);



const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStackScreen = () => (
  <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none"> 
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainStackScreen}
        options={{
          animationEnabled: false
        }}
      />
  </RootStack.Navigator>
);


export default () => {

  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RootStackScreen/>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```